# classify new document - Random Forest, Bag of Words

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, nlp

This is my first attempt of document classification with ML and Python.

1. I first query my database to extract 5000 articles related to money laundering and convert them to pandas df
2. Then I extract 500 articles not related to money laundering and also convert them to pandas df
3. I concatenate both dfs and label them either 'money-laundering' or 'other'
4. I do preprocessing (removing punctuation and stopwords, lower case etc)
5. and then feed the model based on bag of words principle as below:

   ```
   vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer = "word",   
                        tokenizer = None,    
                        preprocessor = None, 
                        stop_words = None,   
                        max_features = 5000) 

   text_features = vectorizer.fit_transform(full_df["processed full text"])    
   text_features = text_features.toarray()    
   labels = np.array(full_df['category'])
   X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(text_features, labels, test_size=0.33)    
   forest = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 100)     
   forest = forest.fit(X_train, y_train)    
   y_pred = forest.predict(X_test)    
   accuracy_score(y_pred=y_pred, y_true=y_test)
   ```

It works fine until now (even though gives me too high accuracy 99%). But I would like to test it on a completely new text document now. If I vectorize it and do              `forest.predict(test)` it obviously says:

```
ValueError: Number of features of the model must  match the input. Model n_features is 5000 and  input n_features is 45
```

I am not sure how to overcome this to be able to classify totally new article.

Comment: The vectorize function maps a corpus of texts into a (multi-dimensional) space. You should check, but from my point of view, since the mapping function is corpus-dependent, it is expected that if you add a new text which is not from the initial corpus of texts, the previous mapping has no trivial meaning on this new text. This is why in your case, with a truly new text, the code does not run. There are ML / statistical methods to solve your question, but I think it is more a statistical challenge than a programming question.

Comment: It sounds like you are re-fitting your vectorizer. Remember, you fit the vectorizer and classifier in the training stage. In the prediction stage you only call transform on the vectorizer and predict on the classifier.

Comment: @probaPerception You're right, the new article should have been fit into the model. Otherwise it has no meaning.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, even though my proposition may work, I strongly emphasize the fact that this solution has some statistical and computational consequences that you would need to understand before running this code. 
Let assume you have an initial corpus of texts `full_df["processed full text"]` and `test` is the new text you would like to test. 
Then, let define `full_added` the corpus of texts with `full_df` and `test`.

```
text_features = vectorizer.fit_transform(full_added)    
text_features = text_features.toarray()
```

You could use `full_df` as your train set (`X_train = full_df["processed full text"]` and `y_train = np.array(full_df['category'])`). 
And then you can run

```
forest = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 100)     
forest = forest.fit(X_train, y_train)    
y_pred = forest.predict(test)
```

Of course, in this solution, you have already defined your parameters and you consider your model robust on new data.

Another remark is that if you have a stream of new texts as input that you would like to analyze, this solution would be dreadful since the computational time of computing a new `vectorizer.fit_transform(full_added)` would increase dramatically.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, it makes sense. I also agree it's not the best solution as with every new article it would have to recalculate the matrix. I have also tried Native Bayes but the training part takes too long and I eventually run out of memory...

Answer (score 1):

My first implementation of Naive Bayes was from Text Blob library. It was extremely slow and my machine eventually run out of memory.

The second try was based on this article http://zacstewart.com/2015/04/28/document-classification-with-scikit-learn.html and used MultinomialNB from sklearn.naive_bayes library. And it worked liked a charm:

```
#initialize vectorizer
count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer = "word",   
                             tokenizer = None,    
                             preprocessor = None, 
                             stop_words = None,   
                             max_features = 5000)
counts = count_vectorizer.fit_transform(df['processed full text'].values)
targets = df['category'].values

#divide into train and test sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(counts, targets, test_size=0.33)

#create classifier
classifier = MultinomialNB()

classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

#check accuracy
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
accuracy_score(y_true=y_test, y_pred=y_pred)

#check on completely new example
new_counts = count_vectorizer.transform([processed_test_string])
prediction = classifier.predict(new_counts)
prediction
```

output:

```
array(['money laundering'], 
      dtype='<U16')
```

And the accuracy is around 91% so more realistic than 99.96%..

Exactly what I wanted. Would be also nice to see the most informative features, I will try to work it out. Thanks everyone.